# Inserting a variable in a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
.createFieldAsXml(`<Field Name="{${kRegion}}" DisplayName="{${kRegion}}" Type="Lookup" List="{${values[1]}}" ShowField="Title" Required="TRUE"/>`);
```

When I try to create a SharePoint List field as such, the field name ends up as `{Region}`.

How should it be formatted to get just `Region`?

Comment: Remove the superfluous outer `{}`…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this formatted as follows:

```
    .createFieldAsXml(`<Field Name="k+${Region}" DisplayName="k+${Region}" Type="Lookup" List="${values[1]}" ShowField="Title" Required="TRUE"/>`);
```